# I need to use <s: property> inside <s:text>

Tags: java, struts2

I think I need to use `<s: property>` inside `<s:text>`, but of course this isn't possible.

Here's the situation: I have a .jsp that needs to display a varying amount of actionmessages. Normally, you would add those actionmessages inside your java class like this:

```
action.addActionMessage("this is a string");
action.addActionMessage("this is another string");
```

However, I don't like to hardcode my message inside the java class, I would like to define it inside a property file, like this:

```
Java:
action.addActionMessage("menu.message1");
action.addActionMessage("menu.message2");

Properties:
menu.message1 = this is a string
menu.message2 = this is another string
```

Of course, the java action class cannot get into the property file, only a struts tags can. so one my .jsp contains this:

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
<s:iterator value="actionMessages">

<div class="loginErrorMessage"> 
    <s:text name="<s:property>"/>
</div>

</s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

I use this iteration construction so I can control the layout of the messages. `<s:property/>` should return the actionmessage itself, which i choose to be equal to a key to an entry in the properties file. If this kind of nested would actually work we would get:

```
      <s:text name="<s:property/>"/>   
==>   <s:text name="menu.message1"/>   
==>   this is a string
```

Can I use OGNL to solve this? I tried some %{} and ${} things but I don't know the name of the value/var to get the string of the message of the valuestack?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial statement is wrong

*Of course, the java action class **can** get into the property file*

You need to extend [`ActionSupport`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html), then you can simply use the [`getText()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29) method to look up text in the resource bundles.

If you really want to go with your hack (I would strongly suggest you don't):

```xml
<s:iterator value="actionMessages" var="key">
    <div class="loginErrorMessage"> 
        <s:text name="%{#key}"/>
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

**N.B.**

If you're using [`ActionSupport.addActionMessage()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#addActionMessage%28java.lang.String%29) you can use the appropriate tag to display all the action messages automatically - [`<s:actionmessage />`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/actionmessage.html). It will even check if they exist or not so you can put it in your jsp and forget about it.

Comment: Although I'm not using it anymore, I just tried the code you suggested and it doesn't show anything. (so %{key} evaluates to an emptry string?)

Comment: @user1884155 sorry, typo. Corrected. (forgot the `#` for a local variable).